# How to delete columns in a table using Office Scripts

Tags: office-scripts

I have a table and I'm looking to delete specific columns for further processing via Office Scripts. Also had a look at the API reference but I was not able to find a method to do so.

I have ~30 columns in total but would like to remove several columns which contain blank row data, after which the plan is to use `getId()` or `getIndex()` to perform further operations on the reduced set of columns.

My concern is that each Excel file does not have a fixed number of columns nor in a specific order, so I guess using `getColumnById` or `getColumnByName` will be a challenge.

The furthest I could get is to identify the column count, but just wondering if there is a way to achieve the above.

```
let headerRangeValues = bodyRange.getColumnCount();
```

Comment: How about let tableCount = table2.getColumns().length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will delete all columns in a table that are completely empty. Let me know if this solves your scenario.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let table = selectedSheet.getTables()[0];
  let body = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
  let headers= table.getHeaderRowRange().getValues();
  for (let column=table.getColumns().length-1; column>=0; column--){
    var entireColumnIsEmpty = true;
    for (let row=0; row<table.getRowCount(); row++){
         if (body[row][column] != ""){
           entireColumnIsEmpty = false;
           break;
         }
         
    }
    if (entireColumnIsEmpty){
      table.getColumnByName(""+headers[0][column]).delete();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect, though maybe better suited for less columns since I have 20+ columns to delete. Sure takes a while but definitely works !

Comment: Since the values are read ahead of time, the script should run quickly for a large number of columns as well. The thing that can slow down this script is the number of rows (large data set).